# Bind to form fields suffixed with []

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some form fields that are posted in with names "value[]":

```
value%5B%5D=8&value%5B%5D=4&value%5B%5D=2
```

They are being posted from a jquery library so I don't have control over this without forking their library.

I tried both `[Bind(Include = "value%5B%5D")]ICollection<int> values` and `[Bind(Include = "value[]")]ICollection<int> values` for the parameter of the action method, and neither worked.

I can verify that the fields are in the request with `Request.Form.GetValues("value[]")`.

I am able to recreate the same issue with a form like so:

```
<form action="/Home/Empty" method="post">
    <input name="value[]" value="5">
    <input name="value[]" value="6">

    <input name="value[]" value="7">}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Empty(List<int> value)
    {  //value is null :(
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Done this. I think I can help. please include your **view source** of the inputs with []

Comment: The javascript library generates the post request on the fly, but I was able to create a form that recreates the same issue.  I have edited to add the markup.

Comment: do the value[] names have indexes? e.g. value[0]? If they have indexes or just don't have []'s it should work.

Comment: see my update on brute forcing through the form array.

Answer (score 1):

What's important is your Action Method's parameter list

- be named same as your input variables

  ```
  public ActionResult Empty(List<int> value)
  ```

The alternative is to iterate through the Request.Form Array.

```
for (i=0; i< Request.Form.count-1; i++)
{
  // somthing to do with Request.Form[i]

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately value is still null :(

Comment: Thanks Dave, yeh as I mentioned I have a workaround of doing `Request.Form.GetValues("value[]")` which returns the array of values.

Comment: @AaronLS, guess I couldn't add anything. Strange situation. Good luck!